# need help on archives pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, archive, wordpress

I want to build my own archives page that displays in the format that I want. I want to show all post title, order by month and year. It should look like this :

```
December 2011
Post title 1
3 comments

Post title 2
4 comments
```

```
November 2011
Post title 1
2 comments
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the specifics of the loop that needs to be created for getting the post title and it's comments order by month.

This is the archives page example I want to build http://spyrestudios.com/archives/.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a superset discussion similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8503001/583539

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WP_Query to do that

Try this code(i don't tested it):

```
<?php
$date = '';
$query = 'posts_per_page=9999';
$queryObject = new WP_Query($query);
// The Loop...
if ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
    while ($queryObject->have_posts()) {
        $queryObject->the_post();
                $my_date = the_date('F j', '', '', FALSE);
                if ($my_date!=$date){
                    echo '<h2>'.$my_date.'</h2>';
                    $date = $my_date;
                }
                echo '<h3>';
                the_title();
                echo '</h3>';
                echo '<span>';
                comments_popup_link('No Comments »', '1 Comment »', '% Comments »');
                echo '</span>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: your code works on what I'm trying to build for my archives page. Many thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

this may help you.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index

Comment: I don't think the referred page has some explanations on how to accomplish this. Maybe I am missing something?