# WordPress: List All Posts and Group Them by Month & Year

Tags: wordpress

When I need to list all posts in 2011 grouped by month, I'd do something like this in WordPress (pretty straightforward as explained [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Usage)):

```
query_posts('monthnum=12&year=2011');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  echo '<li>';
  the_title();
  echo '</li>';
endwhile;
```

Now, how to list ***all posts*** and group them by month *and* year, without knowing how far I should go back? That is, I don't know which year was the oldest post written in. Technically, I could try to do `monthnum=12&year=2010`, `monthnum=12&year=2009`, and so on; but I feel that there must be a better way.

Comment: Look this one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8503565/691506

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to loop through all years:

```
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
     $y=2011-$id;
     query_posts("monthnum=12&year=$y");
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        echo '<li>';
        the_title();
        echo '</li>';
     endwhile; 
 }
```

This may not be an elegant solution, but use it when there is no better one.